# How do we remove the inline style of SmartGwt components?

Tags: textarea, smartgwt

say: When we create a TextAreaItem inline style such as margin, width height etc are set are created along with a style name... How can we get rid of it?

```
<textarea handlenativeevents="false" oninput="isc_TextAreaItem_1.$43g()" tabindex="1052" wrap="SOFT" spellcheck="true" autocomplete="OFF" style="margin:0px;WIDTH:140px;HEIGHT:94px;-moz-user-focus:normal;" cols="10" rows="10" class="textItem" $9a="$9b" $89="isc_TextAreaItem_1" id="isc_5" name="isc_TextAreaItem_0"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi Bali, Thank you for the response, i have edited the code above

Answer (score 0):

U can achieve this by setting **setShowTitle** to **false**
EG : textAreaItem.setShowTitle(false);

Answer (score 0):

```
FormItem.setTextBoxStyle(String)
FormItem.setCellStyle(String)
```